# Upload asset using Earth Engine Python without Cloud Storage buckets?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

Using the JavaScript Code Editor, I know you can simply upload your own assets there by going to the Assets tab (documentation for that linked [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/asset_manager)). I also know you can do it with the earthengine CLI (linked [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/command_line)), but this requires you store the item into a Cloud Storage bucket first.

Isn't there a way to do it through my Python code?

I found this function called ee.data.startIngestion(taskId, request, callback) which sounds like what I'm looking for, but I can't find any good examples on how to use this function.

If you can just simply upload an asset through the JavaScript Code Editor without a Google Cloud account, I think it should be straightforward to do with the Python API too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently cannot upload except through the your browser in the code editor or using Google Cloud Storage.  Note that you get [5GB of cloud storage for free](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/free-cloud-features#storage), and you can manage that space (and uploads) via a python API if you really want to do it from Python. (https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest)